# search a specific item across multiple worksheets and return the list of worksheets that contain the item

Tags: vba, excel

have been trying to work on a automatic stock management, list checking and stock reference system using microsoft EXCEL.

A system or formula which search an specific item from a drop down list which created at cell A5, then list down the name of invoice worksheets that contain that particular item (example, Power Bank) and lastly display the DATE of the worksheet

("DATE" is a named cell that contain the date of the invoice worksheet)
("INVOICE" is a named ranged that contains all the names of invoices)

These are the steps that i'm trying to perform:

1. Search for the item across multiple worksheets
2. List down the worksheets that contain the item
3. List down the particular date of those worksheets

But cant really figure out any useful formulas for them. Been trying on using vlookup, indirect, countifs, iferror. Most of them returns a #REF! error.

[image: Referral Worksheet]

[image: Invoice Example]

Comment: it is difficult to provide an answer without seeing some sample data. Can you put some in your question?

Comment: How do you build the dropdown in A5? Presuming that your list should not include any items which actually exist, the information you want should be contained in the table from which the dropdown takes its list. Depending upon the type of dropdown and method of loading it the list could be in a worksheet or even in the dropdown itself. Thee should be no need to search for that information.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should help:

```
function findString(findStr as string, inWB as workbook) as object
    dim sheet as worksheet, arr as variant, col as new collection, i, j as integer
    for each sheet in inWB.sheets
        arr = sheet.usedrange.value
        if (sheet.usedrange.rows.count =1 and sheet.usedrange.columns.count =1) then
            if inStr(1,arr,findStr)>0 then col.add arr
        else
            for i = 1 to ubound(arr,1)
                for j = 1 to ubound(arr,2)
                    if inStr(1,arr(i,j),findStr)>0 then col.add arr(i,j)
                next j
            next i
        end if
    next sheet
    set findString = col
end function
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution Sancam
But i tried to copy the whole thing to source code, but still nothing happens
Is there anything that i need to edit in the vba?

Comment: Well sure you need to do work with it and for that you need to understand how it works, and what it does. It's often not a good idea to copy and paste VBA posted by a random stranger on the internet directly into Excel without trying to understand the code first... Just saying...

Comment: No problem. Hope it helps :)

Answer (score -1):

These are some of the item tables i created
[Item Table Lists](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eXfFq.png)

This is another invoice example
[Invoice Example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eou9R.png)

Comment: In this forum, *Answers* are for actual answers to the question.  This does not answer your question.  If you want to clarify your question, edit your original question.